# Possible in R Tidyverse to aggregate across rows, combining different age typologies together, only keeping complete age range sets?

Tags: r, aggregate, tidyverse, data-cleaning

I have a tricky challenge on a project that I'm not sure quite how to approach or even if it is possible at all.

I have a dataset where the values for two metrics (MetricA and MetricB here) are scraped from government reports from a range of different countries. The data is in a Tidy (long) format and each row is an observation for one metric for one area for one age group.

I am reporting the age ranges for each metric for those less than 15 years old (and for those who are 15 years old and older. The tricky thing is that many countries, but not all, use that typology.

Those countries where the reported values can't be mapped to this typology are discarded and those countries where data is incomplete for all ages is discarded. So, for example, something which had values for "< 15 years old", "15 to 49", "50+") would be kept, while a different country which had "< 18" and "18-49", but that's it, would be discarded, since it didn't have the "50+" people.

So, the challenge is this, I need to be able to pick out only those countries where the rows for that country cover the full gamut from 0 to whatever (I've been using 199 years old as a hypothetical max age in this case), with no overlap between age categories, with a break in those categories so that the data can be aggregated to form both a LT15 (Less than 15 years old) and a GTE15 (Greater than or equal to 15 years old) category. These are marked by minimum_age and maximum_age in my dataset. The proxy value for maximum_age when the value is to infinity (e.g. "18+" or ">59 years old" is 199.

Ideally this would use Tidyverse, but any package that could make this work would be fine.

A reprex for my dataset is here. In this case the Portuguese data would be discarded because there was no information for the 51 and greater age category.

```
country <- c("USA", "USA", "USA", "USA","Bolivia", "Bolivia", "Bolivia", "Bolivia", "Portugal", "Portugal")
metric <- c("MetricA", "MetricA","MetricB", "MetricB","MetricA", "MetricA","MetricA", "MetricA", "MetricB", "MetricB")
metric_value <- c(12, 10,8, 23, 4, 23, 14, 12, 1, 23)
minimum_age <- c(0, 15, 0, 15, 0, 3, 15, 30, 0, 19)
maximum_age <- c(14, 199, 14, 199, 2, 14, 29, 199, 18, 50)

df <- data.frame(country, metric, value, minimum_age, maximum_age)
```

The output from this would be something like:

```
  country  metric value age_category
1     USA MetricA    12         LT15
2     USA MetricA    10        GTE15
3     USA MetricB     8         LT15
4     USA MetricB    23        GTE15
5 Bolivia MetricA    27         LT15
6 Bolivia MetricA    26        GTE15
```

This doesn't seem like it's possible to me, but I'm sure that I'm missing something here. Is this a challenge that's even doable?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Added an expected output block
EDIT2: Changed the reprex so that the numeric values were being entered as numeric and not as character. Also changed the reprex so that the "value" column was more clearly referring to the metric.

Comment: Thanks, my mistake, corrected.

Comment: Sure, expected output block added.

Comment: No string values, all ages are input as numeric values. This is the output from a separate process where an analyst has already gone through and checked the scraped values and corrected so that all are in the format of a numeric minimum age for the range and a numeric maximum range. For a few reasons, it would be unreliable to have the analyst flag whether the age ranges are complete or not manually unfortunately.

Comment: Yup, exactly. The Portugal cases were eliminated because it was an incomplete age range and so could not be mapped -> aggregated to fit the project typology. The Bolivia cases were aggregated to the respective age categories because they could be directly mapped and then aggregated.

Comment: For the Portugal, as per the example the `value` is between the min and max.  So, it is not clear how it got eliminated i.e. first row range 0 - 18 and value is 1, second row range is 19 to 50 and value is 23

Comment: Apologies, the value is not an age, the value is for whatever metric that row is reporting, say... mortality per 1,000 population or something. Minimum age is the low end of the range for which that value is being reported in the material being scraped, maximum age is the high end of the range for which that value applies. So, to put it another way, a country reporting a mortality rate of 26 per 1000 population among people age 15 and older.

Comment: Portugal was eliminated because there is no data being reported for an age range that extends past 50, so the Portugal data is incomplete, it does not span the entire gamut of the population (missing 50+ years old)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is.continuous` takes a vector of start ages and a vector of end ages and ensures that all ages between the smallest and largest are covered with no overlaps and no gaps returning TRUE if those are all satisfied and FALSE otherwise.   For example

```
is.continuous(c(0, 5), c(4, 8)) 
## [1] TRUE
is.continuous(c(0, 3), c(4, 8)) # overlap so FALSE
## [1] FALSE
is.continuous(c(0, 6), c(4, 8)) # gap so FALSE
## [1] FALSE
```

Now convert the columns that should be numeric to numeric, filter the groups using is.continuous and the other conditions and then categorize the rows, sum and sort.

Regarding the other conditions the question variously refers to the requirement that the maximum be 50+ or that it be equal to 199 and since it was not clear which is the actual condition we used 50+ but we can replace `max(maximum_age) >= 50` with `max(maximum_age) == 199` depending on what is wanted.

```
# return true if every age from minimum to maximum occurs once
is.continuous <- function(st, en) {
  s <- do.call("c", Map(seq, st, en))
  rng <- range(s)
  all(table(c(s, rng[1]:rng[2])) == 2)
}

df %>%
  mutate(value = as.numeric(value), minimum_age = as.numeric(minimum_age), 
   maximum_age = as.numeric(maximum_age)) %>%
  group_by(country, metric) %>%
  filter(is.continuous(minimum_age, maximum_age) && 
    14 %in% maximum_age && 15 %in% minimum_age &&
    max(maximum_age) >= 50) %>%
  group_by(age_category = if_else(maximum_age < 15,"LT15", "GTE15"), .add=TRUE) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value), .groups = "drop") %>%
  arrange(country, metric, desc(age_category))
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  country metric  age_category value
  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>        <dbl>
1 Bolivia MetricA LT15            27
2 Bolivia MetricA GTE15           26
3 USA     MetricA LT15            12
4 USA     MetricA GTE15           10
5 USA     MetricB LT15             8
6 USA     MetricB GTE15           23
```

### Note

The input in the question was slightly changed but above we are using the original input which in reproducible form is:

```
df <- 
structure(list(country = c("USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "Bolivia", 
"Bolivia", "Bolivia", "Bolivia", "Portugal", "Portugal"), metric = c("MetricA", 
"MetricA", "MetricB", "MetricB", "MetricA", "MetricA", "MetricA", 
"MetricA", "MetricB", "MetricB"), value = c("12", "10", "8", 
"23", "4", "23", "14", "12", "1", "23"), minimum_age = c("0", 
"15", "0", "15", "0", "3", "15", "30", "0", "19"), maximum_age = c("14", 
"199", "14", "199", "2", "14", "29", "199", "18", "50")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option with `dplyr`.  Convert the columns types (`type.convert` - as some of the numeric columns were created as character class - by quoting).  Grouped by 'country' 'metric', `filter` out groups that doesn't have 'maximum_age' greater than 50, create a grouping column based on the values in 'minimum_age' and 'maximum_age' and `summarise` the 'value' column by taking the `sum`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(country, metric) %>%
   filter(min(minimum_age) >= 0, max(maximum_age) >= 199) %>%
   group_by(age_category = case_when(minimum_age >= 0 & 
                 maximum_age < 15 ~ "LT15",
         minimum_age >=15 ~ "GTE15"), .add = TRUE) %>% 
   summarise(value = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
#  country metric  age_category value
#* <chr>   <chr>   <chr>        <int>
#1 Bolivia MetricA GTE15           26
#2 Bolivia MetricA LT15            27
#3 USA     MetricA GTE15           10
#4 USA     MetricA LT15            12
#5 USA     MetricB GTE15           23
#6 USA     MetricB LT15             8
```

#### data

```
df <- type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve the issue. While in the Portugal example the issue was that they did not report it for 50+, that was purely one example of something incomplete. The code needs to be able to look for any case where the age rows for a country do not span the full range of population age groups from 0 to 199. This needs to check: 1) do age ranges exist that together cover the full span from 0 to 199?; then 2) can those age ranges be mapped to a 0 to 14 group and a 15 to 199 group?; then the actual aggregation is easy.

Comment: @woggles I changed the `filter` now

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% certain the answer given works for a wider dataset.  The example in the question included a 0-18age band and 18-50age band. But it could be 0-18 and 18+.  0-18 is still to be excluded I think...

I think this does, although it is likely more verbose than it needs to be

```
require(dplyr)
country <- c("USA", "USA", "USA", "USA","Bolivia", "Bolivia", "Bolivia", "Bolivia", "Portugal", "Portugal")
metric <- c("MetricA", "MetricA","MetricB", "MetricB","MetricA", "MetricA","MetricA", "MetricA", "MetricB", "MetricB")
value <- c("12", "10","8", "23", "4", "23", "14", "12", "1", "23")
minimum_age <- c("0", "15", "0", "15", "0", "3", "15", "30", "0", "19")
maximum_age <- c("14", "199", "14", "199", "2", "14", "29", "199", "18", "50")

df <- data.frame(country, metric, value, minimum_age, maximum_age)

keep_case <- function (LT15, LT_valid, GT_valid) {
    case_when(
    LT15 == T & LT_valid ==T ~ T,
    LT15 == F & GT_valid ==T ~ T,
)
}
df %>%
    # Make the numeric values numeric instead of characters
    mutate(
        maximum_age = as.numeric(maximum_age),
        minimum_age = as.numeric(minimum_age),
        value = as.numeric(value)
    ) %>%
    # track if the age range is less than 15 and / or greater than 15
    mutate(
        LT15 = if_else(maximum_age < 15, T,F),
        GTE15 = if_else(minimum_age >=15, T,F)
        ) %>%
    # group the results
    group_by(country, metric, LT15) %>%
    #summarise the results by groups
    summarise(
        value = sum(value),
        min_age = min(minimum_age),
        max_age = max(maximum_age)
    ) %>%
    # Check if Less that 15s cover whole age range
    # Check if over 15s cover whole age range
    mutate(LT_valid = if_else(min_age == 0 & max_age ==14, T, F),
           GT_valid = if_else(min_age ==15 & max_age ==199, T, F)) %>%
    # mark only valid cases to keep
    mutate(keep = keep_case(LT15, LT_valid, GT_valid)) %>%
    # filter off invalid cases
    filter(keep == T) %>%
    # remove the columns not required
    select(c(country, metric, value, age_category =LT15))%>%
    # rename the LT15 from T /F
    mutate(age_category = if_else(age_category==T, "LT15", "GTE15"))
```

Comment: Marked G. Grothendieck's answer as the solution b/c it includes the necessary check for both gaps within the ranges and for overlap in ranges. Thank you! @CALUM Polwart, your solution (slightly repurposed) actually helps with a different bit I'm working on, so thanks there too!